# Set the background color on preferences.xml

Tags: java, android, background

I'm trying to change the background color on `preferences.xml`. The default color is white. Is there a way to change it? It also will be applied to the `preferences.xml` subscreens.

Here, I'm using custom "drawable" to set the background color. The drawable file name is `bg_gradient.xml`. Here is my code:

**res/drawable/bg_gradient.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:gradientRadius="750"
        android:endColor="@color/bg_gradient_end"
        android:startColor="@color/bg_gradient_start"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add that code in styles.xml

```
<style name="PreferencesTheme">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_image</item>
<item name="android:background">#A4A4A4</item>
</style>
```

and set theme for SettingsActivity class in manifest . like this :

```
 android:theme="@style/PreferencesTheme"
```

change background color according to you.